# How can i make a sort of cloth/leather object?

Tags: modeling

I am trying to make Pathfinder from Apex legends and I am at the neck part, he has some sort of leather scarf for his neck, like the bottom part of the gear stick in a car. I have no idea how to tackle this problem so any suggestions would be appreciated

[image]

[image]

Here is the object I am trying to make:

And here is the object i compare it to:

Comment: You can use sculpt mode to use cloth tool or if you plan to animate your model use cloth simulation. See some tutorials.

Comment: are you talking about modeling this part or about the material?

Answer (score 1):

Example with Cloth Simulation ...

[image]

- add *Cylinder*, add horizontal *Loop Cuts* <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> 10, to get square net
- *Invert Selection* <kbd>I</kbd>
- Assign these top/bottom loops (vertices) to a **Vertex Group** under *Properties Editor > Dara > Vertex Group*
- Add *Cloth Simulation* and under *Cloth Sim Properties > Shape > Pin >* choose vertex group
- I animated top part with a *Hook* modifier assigned to *Empty*, but you can parent *Cylinder's* top (or bottom) vertices to any specific part of your character
- For a final touch I added *Subdivision Surface* modifier

[image]